# React - Redux, como posso modificar um objeto complexo?

Tags: react, redux

Estou tentando modificar algumas  propriedades de um array através de um índice vindo de meu `payload`.

O código abaixo percorre o array procurando pelo índice e tenta modicar suas propriedades. Isso até funciona para objetos menos complexos. [Fiz ele com base nessas respostas.](http://How%20to%20update%20single%20value%20inside%20specific%20array%20item%20in%20redux)

Esse é a estrutura do meu objeto.

```
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "sellers": [
            {
              "commertialOffer": {
                 Price: 0,
                 ListPrice: 0,
                 AvailableQuantity: 0
               }
            }]
        }]
    }
```

O que devo fazer para modificar as propriedades de `commertialOffer`?

Estou vindo do Vue e tenho sofrido um pouco com React.

Tenho recebidos alguns erros com `Unexpected token, expected ","`

```
case 'setTotalEstoque':
      return {
        ...state, 
        arrayFavorito: state.contents.map((content, i) => 
          i === action.payload.indice ? {
            ...content,
              items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.Price: action.payload.price,
              items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.ListPrice: action.payload.listPrice,
              items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.AvailableQuantity: item.AvailableQuantity,
          }: content
        )

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça da seguinte maneira, abrindo chave dentro da função e fazendo a atribuição de forma manual.

```
case 'setTotalEstoque':
  const arrayFavorito = state.contents.map((content, i) => {
    if(i === action.payload.indice) {
      content.items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.Price= action.payload.price,
      content.items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.ListPrice= action.payload.listPrice,
      content.items[0].sellers[0].commertialOffer.AvailableQuantity= action.payload.AvailableQuantity,
    }

    return content;
  });

  return {
    ...state, 
    arrayFavorito
  }
```

Comment: Coloquei uma segunda forma, melhorando a organização.